# Creating a clickable div within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for some reason I cannot make this simple thing to work:

```
     for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
      var object = results[i];
      $("#recipes_names").append("<div id ="  + "recipe" + i + " >");
      $("#recipes_names").append(object.get('recipe_title'));
      console.log(object);
      console.log(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('recipe_title'));
      $("#recipe1").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("inside click");
    });
    }
  },
```

I create divs within the "recpie_names" div with the name "recipe0"/"recipe1" etc and I can't for the life of me make them clickable.
I'm sure there's a tiniest of mistakes that I make here but I just can't nail it down.
Can you help me out?

Comment: add a JSFIddle or Stackoverflow snippet. It helps others to easily understand

Comment: Well, you're only binding a click on `#recipe1`....

Comment: where is the generated `div` closing??

Comment: Once I manage to make one to work I'll bind the rest of them

Comment: I'll add a jsfiddle momentarily

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pavelzagalsky/k7aj1q45/

Answer (score 1):

You have to delegates your event

```
$('#recipes_names').on('click', 'div[id^=recipe]', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("inside click");
});
```

Comment: Nope.. Can't make it work :( It looks as if I still press click on the main div

Comment: i forgot the "e" as a parameter.
You may write this outside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the div which is appended and instead of adding event on base of id add just one event on class selector and write just on event:

```
$("#recipes_names").append("<div class='recipe' id ="  + "recipe" + i + " >");
```

and:

```
$(document).on("click",".recipe",function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("inside click");
    });
```

Comment: can you reproduce it in fiddle?

Comment: It's a bit problematic, it's a part of the code that retrieves data from an online service which I don't want to expose it's credentials..

Comment: you can get the json from the firebug that is returned and put it in fiddle

Comment: I'll try to hide the sensitive data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are generating these divs after the fact. So .click will not work.

Try:

```
$("#recipe1").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("inside click");
});
```